# Sync fake audio and media stream for webrtc chrome

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, webrtc, desiredcapabilities

I'm currently using the chrome command-line-switches

```
--use-fake-device-for-media-stream 
--use-file-for-fake-video-capture="file1.y4m" 
--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture="file2.wav"
```

When I launch the following url https://appr.tc/?debug=loopback the audio is not synced correctly with the video.

Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with the https://appr.tc/?debug=loopback site. If you have a similar problem to mine use this site https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/ instead.